# Webservice call return java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: android, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to get the data from the ASMX web service. Ihave used the code from [here](http://androidexample.com/Dot_Net_Webservice_Call_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=100&aaid=122) and used its ConvertWaight web service but its not working.

Its showing me error `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Transport endpoint is not connected`. Ihave added the network permission but still got this error.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Please help me with this any example code will be really helpful.

My web service accept the `NSDictionary` in the iOS. Like this...

```
{
    memberDetails =     {
        DeviceName = "iPhone Simulator";
        DeviceToken = 951fc5a77184ds1a17474256759a34e03d31b708a0358v742df38bb3cc845ds4;
        EmailAddress = "user@org.com";
        IsRemember = True;
        Password = "123456789";
    };
}
```

So in android i have tried to pass the HasMap to the webservice

here is the my web service if it help

```
POST /service/xxx.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xxx.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/SelectByEmailAndPassword"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SelectByEmailAndPassword xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <memberDetails>
        <EmailAddress>string</EmailAddress>
        <Password>string</Password>
        <DeviceToken>string</DeviceToken>
        <DeviceName>string</DeviceName>
        <IsRemember>boolean</IsRemember>
      </memberDetails>
    </SelectByEmailAndPassword>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And Here is my code to call the web service

```
    public String Call(String deviceName, String deviceToken, String emailAddress, String isRemember, String password)
    {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
    PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();

    //Create a HashMap
    Map <String,String> memberDetails =  new HashMap<String,String>();
    //Put data into the HashMap
    memberDetails.put("DeviceName","android Simulator");
   memberDetails.put("DeviceToken","951fc5a77184ds1a17474256759a34e03d31b708a0358v742df38bb3cc845ds4");
    memberDetails.put("EmailAddress","user@org.com");
    memberDetails.put("IsRemember","True");
    memberDetails.put("Password","123456789");

    pi.setName("memberDetails");
    pi.setValue(memberDetails.toString());
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    Object response=null;
    try
    {
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    response = envelope.getResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
    response=exception.toString();
    }
    return response.toString();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is your web service online?

Comment: @nurisezgin Yes it is i am using it in my iPhone App.

Comment: How do you connect to webservice? Are you show your code blocks?

Comment: The code are same as in the link..

Comment: @nurisezgin Checkout my Update.

Answer (score 0):

I check [link](http://androidexample.com/Dot_Net_Webservice_Call_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=100&aaid=122). Than I create Testconnection project. All webservice call must be on the background thread. Could you create I thread and run your target in it?

```
private void getResult()
{
new Thread(){

    public void run() 
    {
        WebserviceCall com = new WebserviceCall();

        // Initialize variables
        final String weight   = "18000";
        String fromUnit = "Grams";
        String toUnit   = "Kilograms";

        //Call Webservice class method and pass values and get response
        final String aResponse = com.getConvertedWeight("ConvertWeight", weight, fromUnit, toUnit);  

        //Alert message to show webservice response
        button.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), weight+" Gram= "+aResponse+" Kilograms",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Log.i("AndroidExampleOutput", "----"+aResponse);
    }

    }.start();

}
```

And than my web service class samely in link;

```
public class WebserviceCall {

     String namespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";
        private String url = "http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertWeight.asmx";

        String SOAP_ACTION;
        SoapObject request = null, objMessages = null;
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport;

        WebserviceCall() {
        }


        /**
         * Set Envelope
         */
        protected void SetEnvelope() {

            try {

                // Creating SOAP envelope          
                envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                //You can comment that line if your web service is not .NET one.
                envelope.dotNet = true;

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(url);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Soap Exception---->>>" + e.toString());   
            }
        }

        // MethodName variable is define for which webservice function  will call
        public String getConvertedWeight(String MethodName, String weight,
                String fromUnit, String toUnit)
          {

            try {
                SOAP_ACTION = namespace + MethodName;

                //Adding values to request object
                request = new SoapObject(namespace, MethodName);

                //Adding Double value to request object
                PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
                weightProp.setName("Weight");
                weightProp.setValue(weight);
                weightProp.setType(double.class);
                request.addProperty(weightProp);

                //Adding String value to request object
                request.addProperty("FromUnit", "" + fromUnit);
                request.addProperty("ToUnit", "" + toUnit);

                SetEnvelope();

                try {

                    //SOAP calling webservice
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                    //Got Webservice response
                    String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();

                    return result;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    return e.toString();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                return e.toString();
            }

        }


}
```

Comment: The web service you called in your called its parameter are simple. But my web service parameter is complex you can see it in my code. Am trying to send nested parameter.